# Extract text from word(docx) document which contains excel tables with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, ms-word, apache-poi

I have a word(docx) document which contains some excel tables inside. When Im trying to extract text like this:

```
        File file = new File("/some file.docx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);

        List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();
```

the result is only text which is not in excel table. I need to get all text from document and I didn't find any solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling a `Paragraph` method then being surprised that you only get paragraphs? What happens if you [request all body elements instead](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#getBodyElements--)?

Comment: I would be surprised if XWPF supported embedded objects at this time. If you find a way to do it (likely it will have to be at the CT level), let me encourage you to donate it back to POI.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. When Im trying to make request all body elements I got this:  Name: /word/document.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml

Comment: public static void readDocxFile2() {
        XWPFDocument doc = null;
        try {
            doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME));
            XWPFWordExtractor ex = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);
            System.out.println(ex.getText());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }